# How to add values to function that will be used in case there is no argument specified?

Tags: python, python-3.7

So, basically i need to make a function that will add 2 ints together and return their sum (a and b). Thing is, if a or b are not specified, the function will by default use a = 0 and b = 1, how can i make the function use these numbers in case there is no argument?

Comment: It is always better if you post an example of your code to see what did you try already.

Comment: welcome to stack Overflow, Can you tell what you have tried so far ?

Comment: -> default arguments: `def f(a=0, b=1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can write

```
def sum(a = 0, b = 1):
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, i thought it would contradict itself and tell me that it's impossible to have 2 = 0.